# how to fix CAN connection errors?

Tags: can-bus, automotive

i'm newbie to the field of automotive, i'm trying to make a connection with can bus between CAN box and aurix board and monitor this connection using CANoe software.

i'm only trying to send a simple message one time from the kit over the can bus as a start just to test the connection and make sure it works before i proceed with the rest of the application.

but all i receive from the kit on CANoe is errors like Form errors, stuff error, CRC error, CAN overload frame.

i checked the pins of the can on the board multiple times to make sure they are correct, also tried to change the CAN channel used on the CAN box, even checked the wires and every thing seems like connected correctly.

and the software i'm using is only a demo that i found inside TASKING compiler demos in the files related the the kit i'm using so i can assume it's not wrong.
the steps i followed to get it this demo to compile are simple

1. use the software platform builder inside TASKING IDE to attach the files related to the kit to the project.
2. include the CAN driver file in it "IfxMultican_Can.h"
3. then i copied and pasted the code inside the documentation within that header file into my project.

i did every thing i could think of to get this to work but still same errors, so it's either the connections are wrong some how or the driver code provided with TASKING IDE contains errors, there is nothing else in the system.

the code i'm using for the project is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SoftwarePlatform/illd_tc29xb/src/ifx/TC29xB/Multican/Can/IfxMultican_Can.h"

// CAN handle
IfxMultican_Can can;

// Nodes handles
IfxMultican_Can_Node canSrcNode;
IfxMultican_Can_Node canDstNode;

// Message Object handles
IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj canSrcMsgObj;
IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj canDstMsgObj;

const unsigned id = 0x100;

int main(){
    // create configuration
    IfxMultican_Can_Config canConfig;
    IfxMultican_Can_initModuleConfig(&canConfig, &MODULE_CAN);

    //initialize module
    //IfxMultican_Can can; // defined globally
    IfxMultican_Can_initModule(&can, &canConfig);

    // create CAN node config
    IfxMultican_Can_NodeConfig canNodeConfig;
    IfxMultican_Can_Node_initConfig(&canNodeConfig, &can);

    canNodeConfig.baudrate = 1000000; // 1 MBaud

    // Source Node
    // IfxMultican_Can_Node canSrcNode; // defined globally
    {
        canNodeConfig.nodeId = IfxMultican_NodeId_0;
        canNodeConfig.rxPin = &IfxMultican_RXD0B_P20_7_IN;
        canNodeConfig.rxPinMode = IfxPort_InputMode_pullUp;
        canNodeConfig.txPin = &IfxMultican_TXD0_P20_8_OUT;
        canNodeConfig.txPinMode = IfxPort_OutputMode_pushPull;

        // initialize the node
        IfxMultican_Can_Node_init(&canSrcNode, &canNodeConfig);
    }

    // Destination Node
    // IfxMultican_Can_Node canDstNode; // defined globally
    {
        canNodeConfig.nodeId = IfxMultican_NodeId_1;
        canNodeConfig.rxPin = &IfxMultican_RXD1B_P14_1_IN;
        canNodeConfig.rxPinMode = IfxPort_InputMode_pullUp;
        canNodeConfig.txPin = &IfxMultican_TXD1_P14_0_OUT;
        canNodeConfig.txPinMode = IfxPort_OutputMode_pushPull;

        // initialize the node
        IfxMultican_Can_Node_init(&canDstNode, &canNodeConfig);
    }

    // IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj canSrcMsgObj; // defined globally
    {
        // create message object config
        IfxMultican_Can_MsgObjConfig canMsgObjConfig;
        IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj_initConfig(&canMsgObjConfig, &canSrcNode);

        // assigned message object:
        canMsgObjConfig.msgObjId = 0;

        canMsgObjConfig.messageId = id; // 'id' is defined globally
        canMsgObjConfig.acceptanceMask = 0x7FFFFFFFUL;
        canMsgObjConfig.frame = IfxMultican_Frame_transmit;
        canMsgObjConfig.control.messageLen = IfxMultican_DataLengthCode_8;
        canMsgObjConfig.control.extendedFrame = FALSE;
        canMsgObjConfig.control.matchingId = TRUE;

        // initialize message object
        IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj_init(&canSrcMsgObj, &canMsgObjConfig);
    }

    // IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj canDstMsgObj; // defined globally
    {
        // create message object config
        IfxMultican_Can_MsgObjConfig canMsgObjConfig;
        IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj_initConfig(&canMsgObjConfig, &canDstNode);

        // assigned message object:
        canMsgObjConfig.msgObjId = 2;

        canMsgObjConfig.messageId = id;
        canMsgObjConfig.acceptanceMask = 0x7FFFFFFFUL;
        canMsgObjConfig.frame = IfxMultican_Frame_receive;
        canMsgObjConfig.control.messageLen = IfxMultican_DataLengthCode_8;
        canMsgObjConfig.control.extendedFrame = FALSE;
        canMsgObjConfig.control.matchingId = TRUE;


        // initialize message object
        IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj_init(&canDstMsgObj, &canMsgObjConfig);
    }

    const unsigned dataLow = 0xC0CAC01A;
    const unsigned dataHigh = 0xBA5EBA11;

    // Initialize the message structure
    IfxMultican_Message txMsg;
    IfxMultican_Message_init(&txMsg, id, dataLow, dataHigh, IfxMultican_DataLengthCode_8);

    // Transmit Data
    while( IfxMultican_Can_MsgObj_sendMessage(&canSrcMsgObj, &txMsg) == IfxMultican_Status_notSentBusy );

    return 0;
}
```

some examples of the errors i get in CANoe

```
   Time            Chn     ID   Name   Event Type   Dir     DLC   Data                                                 
   [-] 18.909137   CAN 1               CAN Error    RxErr         ECC: 100000011xxxxx, Form Error, Bit Position = 12   
   |  ECC          100000011xxxxx            
   |  Code         Form Error                
   |  Position     12                        
   |  ID           0010010011001b (499)      
   |  DLC          9                         
   |  Data 00-07   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

another example

```
   Time            Chn     ID   Name   Event Type   Dir     DLC   Data                                                
   [-] 18.907080   CAN 1               CAN Error    RxErr         ECC: 100001001xxxxx, CRC Error, Bit Position = 36   
   |  ECC          100001001xxxxx            
   |  Code         CRC Error                 
   |  Position     36                        
   |  ID           0010010011001b (499)      
   |  DLC          9                         
   |  Data 00-07   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

i also must point that despite i only send the message once, i keep receiving a non-ending sequence of those errors until i stop the simulation.

is there any way i can use to better understand how to fix those errors?
any information about the kit pins numbering or the correct connection for can would be very helpful.
i also must point that i'm only using the driver for the can abstractly from how it works, i only understand the CAN as bus on which i'll throw a message and receive it from the other end using some functions i don't know how it actually works and the time i have is quite limit and doesn't allow me to learn that much.

board used : KIT_AURIX_TC297_TFT
, CAN box    : VN6510A

Comment: These really seem to be errors on a physical level. Hard to diagnose it from here, but here are some suggestions:

- Check your cables. Just connect the two CAN-ports of your Vector device and see whether you can correctly receive messages from one port to the other

- Check the pull up resistors. The cables coming with the vector interface should have them built-in. Termination with 120 Ohms is needed

Comment: Another potential issue just came to my mind:

Check whether the baudrate of the vector interface is set to 1 Mbps (as given in your sample code)

Comment: hello there, thanks for your reply, the can box was tested before so it's guaranteed to be working, also the connection cables seem fine.

Comment: i checked the board output with oscilloscope and it gives nothing; the problem is probably in either the kit itself (not likely), or i may 've used wrong pins as i don't have the pin map of the kit i just used the two pins from can0 pins as this [link](http://www.interfacebus.com/Can_Bus_Connector_Pinout.html), or with the can driver; i can see some todo comments in it and some functions in it aren't defined so i'm working to find another driver now.

Comment: by the way i asked infinion to provide the user manual of the kit itself as the user manual i have is regarding the processor but no reply yet, that's why i don't have pin map, any info about it would be really appreciated.

Comment: oh, and also the baud rate was checked before, i even lowered it to 500,000 after wards in both the code and CANoe just in case the relatively high speed causes a problem with cables but it wasn't the problem either.

Comment: correction : the oscilloscope doesn't give out nothing, it gives a signal with value zero probably that's why i get stuff error.

Comment: I would still recommend to rule out a wiring issue. Turn off the supply and measure the resistance between CAN_H and CAN_L. That should be around 60 Ohms. The turn on the supply and meadows the voltage between CAN_H and GND as well as between CAN_L and GND. That should be around 2-3 Volts (for a idle network).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your baudrate in CANOe from 500.0 to 1000.0 Kbps (as configured in infineon iLLD canNodeConfig.baudrate = 1000000; // 1 MBaud)

Also, make sure you have 120 Ohm resistor between CANH and CANL.

Try to see your output from microcontroler (CAN TX/CAN RX) in oscilloscope or logic analyser, also the output from your CAN transceiver, since you are using TFT board you already have the transceiver resistor.